# Remove any ssh-keygen commands from init scripts

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit server. I'm following this guide:

Secure Secure Shell
https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html

It includes the instruction:

> remove any ssh-keygen commands from the init script.

How do I accomplish this on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu does not have `ssh-keygen` in init scripts. Ubuntu generates keys using `dpkg-reconfigure` triggers. It is not an automatic action.

```
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

The quoted line refers to Fedora/RHEL/CentOS, which is using `sshd-keygen` service. It creates keys before running the `sshd` service itself and is triggered by `AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS` variable in `/etc/sysconfig/sshd`. Removing something from init scripts is not a good advice. More correct would be to set `AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=no` in above mentioned file.